# Proving whether linearly independent

Tags: matrices

I've been working on this for almost half hour, can someone answer this question perhaps? Thanks.

Let {$\vec u_1, \vec u_2, \ldots , \vec u_k$} be a linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\vec v$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$  \vec v = c_1 \vec u_1 + \cdots + c_k \vec u_k$$

for some scalars $c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_k$, with $c_1 \ne 0$. Prove that {$\vec v, \vec u_2, \ldots , \vec u_k$} is linearly independent.

Comment: Edit your post to include what you have tried. Also, I didn't know what $c_1 !=0$ meant (why is there an exclamation?) so I left it in.

Comment: @Mattos he meant $\ne$, like in programming

Answer (score 1):

suppose the converse:

if they are linearly dependent,we have scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_{(k-1)}$ that $v=a_1u_2+\cdots+a_{(k-1)}u_k=c_1u_1+\cdots+c_ku_k$ so  ....

u can complete the proof!try a little!

Comment: Note the correct spelling of "scalar". (I changed it.)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& b_1 \vec v + b_2 \vec u_2 + \cdots + b_n \vec u_k \\[8pt]
= {} & b_1(c_1 \vec u_1 + \cdots + c_k \vec u_k) + b_2 \vec u_2 + \cdots + b_n \vec u_k \\[8pt]
= {} & (b_1 c_1) \vec u_1 + (b_1 c_2 + b_2 ) \vec u_2 + \cdots + (b_1 c_k + b_k) \vec u_k \tag a
\end{align}
If this adds up to $\vec 0$ then, since $\vec u_1, \ldots, \vec u_k$ are linearly independent, all of the coefficients in line $(\text{a})$ must be $0$.  That implies $b_1 c_1=0$.  But it is given that $c_1\ne0$; therefore $b_1=0$.  Thus the rest of the coefficients in line $(\text{a})$ reduce to $b_2, \ldots, b_k$, and they must all be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint** $(\vec{u}_k)$ linearly independent means $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\vec{u}_i = 0$ has a unique solution $a_i \equiv 0$.

Assume $v, \vec{u}_2, \ldots$ is not linearly independent. That means there is a non-zero solution to $a_1v + a_2 \vec{u}_2 + \ldots + a_k \vec{u}_k = \vec{0}$. Substitute the definition of $\vec{v}$ and use the linear independence of the $u$'s to get a contradiction.